# (EC)DSA signature without hashing, or with offloaded hash?

Tags: hash, dsa, cryptographic-hardware

In (EC)DSA as per [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf), the message to sign is first hashed. Imagine that we skip this hashing stage, instead put the message where the hash was, and constrain the size of message $h$ to the original hash's output width $N$ bits. The resulting scheme is vulnerable to (at least) these existential forgeries ($q$ is the multiplicative group order):

- any signature for message $0\le h<2^N-q$ is also valid for message $h+q$;
- a valid signature for messages $h=0$ and $h=q$ is easy to obtain: in DSA, $(r,s)$ with $r=s=y\bmod q$ does the trick, where $y$ is the public key; there's an analog with [ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm), which $r=s=x_A\bmod q$, where $x_A$ is the $x$ coordinate of the public key, and $q=n$.

These are easily solved by further restricting the message space to $[1,q)$.

Are other attacks possible? In particular, does temporary access to a signing oracle allow a total break (key extraction or other mean to sign any message)?

---

The question is of direct interest when one wants to lower the communication overhead between a signing device and a host using it to (EC)DSA-sign large messages: can we fully offload the hash computation to the host? I believe that holds (and as noted in comments, that seems to be practice), but can we demonstrate that? If not, how can we safely offload most of that computation, without breaking standard conformance?

Comment: From what I can tell, off-loading the hashing to middleware on the host is already (commonly?) done in practice.

Comment: @SEJPM: I know examples of hash offloading (and even padding offloading) in RSA signature, where that is quite convincingly safe. If you have a public reference to an example of hash offloading for (EC)DSA, I'd like to know.

Comment: My [Smartcard-HSM](https://www.smartcard-hsm.com/) supports that using the [OpenSC](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki) middle-ware (ie it claims plain ECDSA support and ECDSA-SHA1 support), if I find more I'll link it.

Comment: @SEJPM Which doesn't prove that it is safe to do so of course. RSA has an additional padding step. The hashing isn't the issue, the issue is that the ECDSA calculation afterwards becomes completely available to an attacker (even if it is still randomized - if it is secure then the answer should be somewhere in there)

Comment: My feeling is that if there were serious attacks against (EC)DSA without the hash function, these would be well-known. (But of course, I could have missed something well-known.) Also, there are hash-less variants of (EC)DSA (replacing the mod q/x-coordinate mod n with a random oracle) where you can simulate the signing oracle, so that a key recovery attack turns into a straight-forward d.log. computation.

Comment: On a different note it is baffling why, in the standard, it was decided *not* to include the randomness $r$ (along with the message) in computing the hash. The security proof ([Pointcheval and Stern](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs001450010003)), which uses the  forking lemma, *crucially* relies on $r$ being a part of the hash --- no proof is known otherwise. This was common knowledge at the time!

Comment: I might be a little bit late here, but is there any resource on your claims? I am facing a similar problem, considering I can't fit a hash algorithm on my device's memory anymore. I'd really like to know what kind of dangers I am running into without hashing the message, but I can't really find any resources

Comment: @fgrieu What I meant is: at the time of standardisation it was known that there are close variants of DSA (e.g., [DSA-II](http://www.di.ens.fr/users/pointche/Documents/Papers/2000_pkcB.pdf) or the [Pointcheval-Stern signature](http://www.di.ens.fr/users/pointche/Documents/Papers/1996_eurocrypt.pdf)) that were provably secure. These basically involve a minor modification, that of computing $h=H(m,r)$ instead of just $h=H(m)$. But these were ignored.

Comment: @Occams Trimmer: this DSA-II signature scheme is standardized as the Pointcheval/Vaudenay algorithm at least since [ISO/IEC 14888-3:2006](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:14888:-3:ed-2:v1:en) (It is not to be confused with the Pintsov-Vanstone Elliptic Curcve signature scheme with message recovery, aka ECPVS, PVSSR, ECSSR-PV of [ISO/IEC 9796-3:2006](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:9796:-3:ed-2:v2:en)). Too bad that's not in [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's focus on DSA. The signing on a message $m\in \mathbb{Z}_q$ for the suggested "no-hash" protocol is done as follows:

1. Pick $k\in_R \mathbb{Z}_q$, compute $r=f(g^k)$, where $f(\cdot):=(\cdot \bmod p) \bmod q$.
2. Compute $s=k^{-1}(m+xr)\bmod q$
3. Return $(r,s)$ if the signature is not degenerate.

The verification algorithm, on input $(m,s,r)$, checks if $f((g^m\cdot y^r)^{(1/s)})=r$.

The following consists of a forgery on a random message under the key-only attack.

1. Let $K=g^a\cdot y^b$, where $a,b\in_R\mathbb{Z}_q$
2. Compute $r=f(K)$, and set $s=r/b$
3. Return $(r,s)$ as a forgery on $m=(a\cdot r)/b$

This attack is implicit in [FKP], which studies the security of EC(DSA) (in a restricted model).

[FKP]: Fersch, Kiltz and Poettering, [*On the One-Per-Message Unforgeability of (EC)DSA and its Variants*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/890), TCC 2017

Comment: This indeed is a working existential forgery. The verifier computes $f((g^m\cdot y^r)^{(1/s)})$, that is $f((g^{a\,r/b}\cdot y^r)^{(b/r)})$, that is $f(g^a\cdot y^b)$, and that matches $r$. The signature $(y,y)$ for message $0$ of the question is a special case with $a=0$ and $b=1$. However, as is, the message $m$ signed is uncontrolled; and temporary access to a signing oracle does not yield a total break.

Comment: _@However, as is, the message m signed is uncontrolled; and temporary access to a signing oracle does not yield a total break._
That's correct. Let's see if the attack can be extended.

Comment: Does this show that DSA is not secure when there is no hash protocol?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown In some sense, yes.